# Finding function declarations in Ubuntu on Python

Tags: python, graph-tool

I have a vaguely defined function of a class Graph of a module I call gt (it is graph-tool). so i declare g = gt.graph() then want to use g.degree_property_map but do not know how. Therefore I want to see where in code g.degree_property_map or in this case just the function, is defined. How can I find that? I'm working on command line on a vm.

Thanks

For reference the library in question is graph-tool - http://projects.skewed.de/graph-tool/

Also I am currently importing it using from graph_tool.all import * . that is of course somewhat of a problem.

Comment: Try `grep 'def degree_property_map' *.py`

Comment: where should I do that? I assume the python 2.7 bin?

Comment: @mgilson already suggested below.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf -- I see, you're correct, someone did suggest that.  Sorry :).

Comment: @larsman how should i do that recursively. Sorry I'm doing grep -r 'def degree_property_map' ./*.py and it isn't happy so how can i do the current directory recursively for *.py

Comment: I think `grep -r 'def ...' .` should do the trick.  This will pick up more than just `.py` files, but that's probably OK.

Comment: that's what I'm trying now .. .still not finding it ._. where should I run it? I'm currently running it in /usr/ . i'm not sure where apt-get install graphtool installed it....

Comment: @mgilson and as you can see whereis is being helpful:

user@comp/usr/share/pyshared$ whereis graphtool
graphtool:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open interactive python (type `python` and hit ENTER on the command line), you should be able to run the command `help(<graph's module name>)`, then, under the `FILE` section of the help documentation that is generated, you should see the absolute path to the code you are interested in.

For example, I just ran:

```
import numpy
help(numpy)

# Returned documentation containing:
# FILE
# /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py
```

Also,

```
import my_module # A module I just created that contains the "Line" class
help(my_module)

# Returned documentation containing:
# FILE
# /home/<my user name>/Programming/Python/my_module.py
```

Comment: returns doc strings. the doc strings are .... really bad so that doesn't help here. that's why I wanted code.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `inspect.getsource(gt.Graph.degree_property_map)`. (You have to `import inspect`.)

Of course, what you pass into `getsource()` will change depending on how you imported `Graph`. So if you used `from graphtools.all import *`, you'd just need to use `inspect.getsource(Graph.degree_property_map)`.

Comment: ok! and way to do this via a macro in vim or the like? I really like eclipse's see declaration

Comment: Specifically you want to be able to do this in vim? Would running a script from the command line suffice?

Comment: @Matthew, I was foiled. forgot. In order to call it you do from graphtools.all import *. that means I got:


http://pastie.org/5075054

Comment: Does my edit help? Also, I don't know how to do this in `vim`, sorry.

Comment: Uhm... what is your second one.. I am not really sure how to use it

Comment: I was just giving an example with a different module. I just changed it. What exactly am I looking at at the pastie link?

Comment: that is what happens when i try inspect.getsource(gt.Graph.degree_property_map)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a normal function (not a builtin, ufunc, etc) you can try using the `func_code` attribute

For example:

```
>>> inspect.iscode
<function iscode at 0x02EAEF30>
>>> inspect.iscode.func_code
<code object iscode at 02EB2B60, file "C:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 209>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I just did help(graph_tool) and manually jumped through code. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: If the `help()` answer was the one that helped you out the most, you should accept it instead of mine.